# handshake failure In salesforce

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, handshake-failure

I have some code that I use to sync my salesforce contact to wordpress. Below is the sample code.

```
public with sharing class AS_httpSyncToWordpress {


    @future (callout=true)
    public static void sendAPIRequestInsert(Set<Id> setAllId) {
        Contact[] allContact= [Select Id,FirstName,LastName,Email FROM Contact where ID IN :setAllId];

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        String username = 'sampleusername';
        String password = 'samplepassword';

        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
        EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

        // below is just a sample endpoint
        req.setEndpoint('https://mysampleEndpoint.com:8080/wp-json/myApi/v1/create_contact');
        req.setMethod('POST');
    //    req.setHeader('Content-Length','2004');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setBody(JSON.serialize(allContact));
    //    req.setCompressed(true); // otherwise we hit a limit of 32000
        System.debug('allContact : ' + allContact); 
        System.debug('REQUEST : ' + req);
        try { 
            res = http.send(req);
            System.debug('RESPONSE wew ' + res.getBody());
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Many months ago it is working well. But when I've tried it lately I received an error saying :

> ```
> System.HttpRequest retrying request in response to handshake failure: 
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: 
> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
> ```

So what I did is that I've tried to call the wordpress api using postman. It is working well. So I assume that the problem resides in the salesforce part. Can you please give me an idea why it is not working at the moment?

Comment: The web server or the URL you are connecting to does not have a valid certificate from an authorized CA. Directly access the endpoint through the browser and see does it barf. You could also look at [SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) to diagnose problems with your SSL certificate.

Comment: @TSmith Thank you. What I am wondering is that, on the previous months, it is working well and as I remember, we didn't tackle certificates in our code.

Comment: @Hope The error is likely saying that the certificate expired, it's possible it was set up before you created this integration, was automatically used for the endpoint and has now expired.